# Маслины, маслинами

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология

...И ему больше ничего не оставалось как только спрятаться за маслины/маслинами (деревья/деревьями).

Какой из вариантов является верным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

СПРЯТАТЬСЯ — 1. **куда (за что) (направление действия).** Солнце точно играет в прятки: то спрячется за облако, то опять обольёт светом (Н.-П.); Пашка спрятался за корзину с красными цветами (Пауст.). **2. где (за чем) (место действия).** Сваакер... спрятался за стволом соседней ветлы (Фед.); Мы придём заранее и спрячемся за сценой (Нос.).

Управление в русском языке

Д. Э. Розенталь.

Comment: верны оба варианта?

Comment: Да. Оба варианта верны. Первый указывает на направление, другой - место действия.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказано, верны оба варианта.

В.п. и Т.п. могут иметь иметь пространственное значение, которое в данном случае совпадает, при этом используется один и тот же предлог ЗА.

**Основным значением Т.п.** является орудийное значение, то есть сущ. в форме Т.п.  в общем случае способствует осуществлению  действия. В данном случае — спрятаться где?, указание на место: спрятаться за маслинами.

**Основным значением В.п.** является направленность действия на предмет, а в случае предложного управления — относительно предмета: спрятаться за маслины, за предмет.

Comment: Спасибо-спасибо, ответ исправлен